# while retrieving string into json from database facing error

Tags: java, json, web-services, scala, playframework

I am new to play frame-work as well as scala language, what i want to i want to convert my arraylist into json, in java i am 1st storing values into list and then converts list into json like this `public static Result getJson(){
         List<Task> abc = Task.all();
         return ok(toJson(abc));
  }`

through this code i achieved the same but when i am trying the same approach in scala then it is not working : code is  `def jsonTask= Action {
  var jsonValue:List[Task] = Task.all()
  Ok(views.html.display(Json.toJson(jsonValue))) }` and i am facing error ::

**No Json deserializer found for type List[models.Task]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.**

Some one gives me solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Define an implicit writer in your model class.

```
implicit val implicitTaskWrites = new Writes[Task] {
def writes(taskobj: Task): JsValue = {
  Json.obj(
    "id" -> taskobj.id,
    "label" -> taskobj.label
  ) 
}
```

}

This will convert each Task (my model class) object into JsValue object.
Then

```
   def parse(list :List[Task]) :String ={

     var json=new JsArray()
     for(task:Task <- list ){
        json=json.append(Json.toJson( task ) )
     }

     json.toString()
 }
```

Add this code also.

then if you call parse(list)  , can get the json string.

Answer (score 0):

Could you send us your view file?

Did you try to take a `scala.List` parameter in your `.scala.html` file, instead of just `List`?

EDIT: why do you send JSON to your view? Shouldn't you either return directly the Json (`Ok(JsArray(jsonValue))`) or use your list in your view?

Comment: i changed List to Scala.List but it is not working, gives me array with Empty value inside

Comment: if i am not using view then it will gives me result something like

{"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}

Comment: What about `Ok(JSONArray(jsonValue))`?

Comment: OK sorry, now that I tried that in a Play application, I found the solution: try `JsArray`, filled with `JsValue`. For example:                    `Ok(JsArray(List("Test").map(JsString)))`

Comment: not found: value JsArray
i posted my function in question so what kind of changes you did so that it is working for you? Can you please mention it? AND do i have to import anything?

Comment: Import `play.api.libs.json.JsArray`

Comment: can you write the entire function again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a parameter in your display.scala.html
@(jsonTasks: play.api.libs.json.JsValue)

Comment: without view it's give me empty value in array but with view it gives me an error at the point where i am converting list into json, so not able to check your solution.

Comment: I've seen the comments of Adrien Aubel and yours, if you are getting the values in the list try "Ok(Serialization.write(list))" by importing "import net.liftweb.json.{ NoTypeHints, Serialization }"

Answer (score 0):

You can use toJSon method in the library play.libs.Json
Step:
  First:
      import play.libs.Json;

Then use

```
  ok(JSon.toJson(list));
```

to display the converted json.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result but with the different approach..

I used the approach of key,value map`val results= SQL("SELECT * FROM exercise").apply()

var a:Int=0
 for(a<- 0 to results.length-1)
 {val jsonrec=Json.obj("id" ->results(a)Long,"label"->results(a)String
    )
 output.add(jsonrec)
    }'...

But it could be better if i get the answer with the approach i used and posted question..